# Environment variable in unicorn script

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I want to configure the worker processes depending on the environment. 
But how should I use the condition in unicorn script w.r.t environment variabes.

I have used following code but does not work -

```
    if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "development"
      worker = 1
    elsif ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "staging" || ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == "testing"
      worker = 2
    else
      worker = 16
    end

    worker_processes worker
```

Answer (score 0):

If you see the code to define the [Rails.env](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3096629d297a77a9b64747a0ac2df6b2cbf47a68/railties/lib/rails.rb#L81):

```
# File railties/lib/rails.rb, line 81
def env
  @_env ||= ActiveSupport::StringInquirer.new(ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || ENV["RACK_ENV"] || "development")
end
```

Return "development" if ENV["RAILS_ENV"] and ENV["RACK_ENV"] are blank.

So you must use the Rails.env in your script or change it.

Comment: is ENV["RAILS_ENV"] available when unicorn starts? I tried something similar but with Rails.env and no luck.